# Фильтрация массива методом filter

Tags: javascript

Задан массив значений, в нем могут быть обычные элементы и подмассивы. Используя метод `filter` мне нужно оставить в нем только подмассивы.

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы прочитали, как работает [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите оставить только массивы, то вероятно это поможет

```
let arr = [1, 'string', [3, 4], 5, [6, 7]];

let filtrate = arr.filter(Array.isArray);
console.log(filtrate)
```

Comment: так все помогло, спасибо